# Best practice for storing and referencing 3rd party source code

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

Currently our main product solution is stored in a single TFS project, and all 3rd-party libraries that are referenced by our projects are pulled in from nuget, so the binary files are not stored in TFS. Now we are having to create a customized fork of one of the libraries (class library) that our product will reference. The library we are going to "fork" lives on codeplex as a TFS/SVN style project that we don't control, so we only have read access to it via the SVN interface, meaning there's no way to do a proper fork like you might be able to do with a git project. As such, our fork has to live elsewhere, disconnected from the codeplex project going forward. Since we use TFS for our main product, we'd like to store the fork and develop it in our TFS environment.

What is the best practice for storing this library in TFS so that our main project can reference it? Should it be in its own TFS Project? How should another project in TFS reference the library?

Answer (score 3):

The team Project is a choice that you will have to make as to which best suits you, either a new stand alone isolated project or whether it just sits with in your current one project, it really depends on how much development work you are going to do with it and whether you want to be able to manage that through the same sprints etc.

To consume it i would just build it and create a NuGet Package and consume it in the same way as you do with all the rest of your referenced projects, obviously you may need to have this in your own NuGet feed.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only project that requires this customized library, put it in a folder inside of your current project that is parallel to your Sources (now cloaking is not required). Create a manual triggered build definition that builds the library and creats a NuGet package. Use a post-build script (or modify nuget.target) to push that NuGet library to your NuGet repository. Then reference this in your daily build.

You can overlay new releases from codeplex in your folder structure, if needed.